# SSL Decryption programmatically

Tags: openssl, wireshark, encryption, diffie-hellman

I want to decrypt the packets which is using the ciphersuite TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA.Using Master keys I am able to decrypt the data in wireshark.Still I can't save decrypted wireshark file so I am doing it programmatically.I am having Keyblock which includes client mac,server mac,client write,server write and both client and server iv's .So how can I decrypt encrypted data programmatically?

Comment: "Diffie-Hellman" is a key exchange, not an encryption algorithm

Comment: Yes.Its using the cipher suite TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA

Comment: The nature of DHE ciphersuites is such that you cannot decrypt them in wireshark. You must use a non-DHE ciphersuite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to fork Wireshark and make a patch which allows you to save decrypted data (then give them the patch to incorporate if they so desire).

They've already done all the hard work, all you need to do is add some basic file I/O, and it also contributes back to the development of a program you're using.